# Join showing non-existent records

Tags: sql, join

I am so confused what is happening with my database. I've used Join to join 3 tables with this:

```
Select hotel.hotelName, hotel.city, room.price, booking.guestNo
From hotel
Join Room on room.HotelNo = hotel.HotelNo
Join Booking on booking.hotelNo = hotel.hotelNo
Where (guestNo= 987)
```

Booking 987 only has 2 records of him booking 2 separate hotels but I'm getting 3 records in the query. Why is this happening? Where did the extra record come from?

EDIT: But when I remove price and add the guest table instead of the price table as shown:

```
Select hotel.hotelName, hotel.city, guest.guestName, booking.guestNo
From hotel
Join Booking on booking.hotelNo = hotel.hotelNo
Join Guest on guest.guestNo = booking.guestNo
Where (guest.guestNo= 987)
```

The actual 2 records show, not 3.

Comment: Not enough information.  However, I suspect that the hotel room has more than 1 price defined. If so, then the query needs to be refined by the room.price as well. (Many hotels have more than one price for a room.)

Comment: What if one booking was for two separate rooms? That would also generate an extra record in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the hotel room has more than one (1) price defined. (Many hotels have more than one price for a room.) If so, then the query needs to be refined by the room.price as well.

This could *perhaps* be resolved by:

```
Select hotel.hotelName, hotel.city, room.price, booking.guestNo
From hotel
Join Room on room.HotelNo = hotel.HotelNo
Join Booking on booking.hotelNo = hotel.hotelNo
Where (guestNo= 987) and room.Price = 155.89
```

However, without access to the schema this is just a guess.

It likewise could be that the room has a rate and a special rate or two.  In that case you would need to know what'special rates' exist and was applied to your customer.